What table environments do I need to know?
There are so many environments for creating tables in LaTeX: array, tabbing,tabular, tabular*, tabularx, longtable, tabu, longtabu, tblr, and probably many more.
Each of these have their own features and shortcomings, but I find it very frustrating to have to plow through a lot of documentation each time I need a slightly sophisticated table.
So, is there a subset of these environments that provides all the features I may reasonably need? If so, I could study them in detail and forget about the rest.

Many different needs, many different solutions. Without seeing what level of sophistication you want, it's impossible to say more.

there is very little overlap in the ones you mention. tabbing doesn't make tables, tabular and tabular* are standard latex and identical code except the * form allows you to supply a target table width,  tabularx is like tabular* but varies the width by controlling the width for linebreaking, tabu and longtabu are broken and unmaintained so not usable. tblr is actively maintained and with lots of features but somewhat slow and experimental.  You need to make a choice there is no general right answer.

@DavidCarlisle You missed longtable ;).

You only need to learn the ones you want to use and which currently work. But some of the later packages are based on or extend the ideas of earlier ones, even if they're implemented differently. For that reason, I think it makes sense to start with more basic environments and learn the more involved ones only when you get frustrated because you can't do what you want with what you know.

I am a tabularray evangelist. It does everything you need for tables:  span cells, adjustable width columns, color borders, color cells, format and content separated, tables with notes, cells with notes, better spacing (and adjustable also), long tables, etc. Yes, its somewhat slower than the other packages, but it is a sacrifice worth willing for me.

There is also NiceTabular of the nicematrix package ...

It is probably good to know all of them at least regarding their basic functionality. I would recommend that you get familiar with tabular since this is the basic LaTeX environment. Then, check out the array package. Ignore tabu and longtabu, but do look at tabularx and longtable. Due to its complexity and different approach, look a the tabularray package (with its tblr environment) last.
